# For $f: \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ continuous and $b>0$ prove the following:

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

For $f: \Bbb R\rightarrow  \Bbb R$  continuous and $b>0$ such that

> $ f(0)\neq -1$ and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{b} f(t)  \, dt=0$

Show that the equation

> $\displaystyle\int_{x}^{a} f(t)  \, dt=x$

has, for $a$ close enough to $b$, a unique solution $x=x(a)$ in $\Bbb R$, where $x(a)$ is close to $0$. Show that $x(a)$ is of class $C^1$ and compute $x'(b)$. What goes wrong if the function is $f(t)=-1+2t$ and $b=1$.

So far, I'm kind of lost with this question, so any suggestions you have will be of great help.

Comment: What is "$=/=$"? Does it mean "$\neq$"?

Comment: Yes, just fixed it.

Comment: Are you sure there is not some additional condition such as $f$ strictly increasing?

Comment: As an example, let $f(t) = 100 \cos t,$ $b = 4\pi,$ $4\pi - 10^{-6} < a < b.$ Solve $x + 100 \sin x = 100 \sin a \approx 0.$ How many solutions are there where $0 < x < b$?

Comment: The phrasing of the problem (an a close enough to b leading to a unique solution) brings to mind trying to use the contraction mapping theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\,dt$ so that $F(b) = 0, F(0) = 0, F'(0) \neq -1$. The equation to solve is $F(a) - F(x) = x$ where $a$ is near $b$. Differentiating the equation with respect to $a$ we get $F'(a) - F'(x)x'(a) = x'(a)$ so that $x'(a) = \dfrac{f(a)}{1 + f(x(a))}$. Now that when $a = b$ then $x(a) = 0$ so that $x'(b) = \dfrac{f(b)}{1 + f(0)}$. This is where we need that $f(0) \neq -1$. Proving the existence / uniqueness of $x(a)$ seems difficult without further constraints.

Comment: I have a strong hunch that something was left out of the problem statement, such as that $f$ is an increasing function.

Comment: @DavidK: I too feel the same but without any further input from OP I can't say anything.